# a challenging list question on prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am new on prolog. Can you help me to solve this problem, please.

exam(math, paul).

exam(phys, paul).

exam(cmpe, sofia).

exam(bio, george).

I want to implement the predicate otherExam(L, N). L is a lesson, and N is the list of all lessons (except L) haved by student of L.

otherExam(math,X). returns [phys]

otherExam(cmpe,X). returns []

otherExam(chem,X). returns false (no such lesson)

otherExam(math,[phys]) returns true

otherExam(X,[phys]). returns math

I haved stucked with this problem. If you help me, I will be very happy :))

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you showed what you have tried, also is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

check [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) and [select/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3)

findall/3 is used to get all the possible results from a query
for example, findall(X,ancestor(X,paul),L) will find all X such as X is an ancestor of paul and will put them in the list L

Comment: OK. Actually I see what you mean.
I must do sth like that;

otherExam(L,N) :- findall(T,(exam(T,_,_,_),(I need sth here)), Ts) , select(L, Ts, N).

but I could not check whether person have two exam or not :(

Comment: well, if the person has only one exam the list N will be empty. if you want the predicate otherExam/2 to fail if there is not any other exam, you could write it like this:
otherExam(L,N):-
fidnall(Lesson,exam(Lesson,_),Lessons), select(L,Lessons,List), not_empty(List).
not_empty([_|_]). <-basically ensures that there is at least one element in the list